# How to capture logcat logs and print while testing with appium?

Tags: appium, logcat

I am testing application in automation using appium.
App is getting crash many times while performing scroll and swipe action on random element.
I want to capture `logcat` logs. 
Store them in file.
Logs on console of failed step.
And want to print them with console log.

Is there any code to perform this action please let me know.

Comment: Please share your code so far

Comment: @frianH : Thanks for response but i'm seeking code. I do not have code.

Comment: AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
    .withIPAddress("")
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .usingDriverExecutable(new File(""))
    .withAppiumJS(new File(""))
    .withLogFile(new File("")) <<<-------------------This will do the trick
    .build();